# It's better to hardcore constant values than make query to DB?

Tags: mysql, database, forms, html-select

I have quite complicated form which contains a lot of values and I wonder, which option is better from performance perspective:

- **Load** the data () from the database
- **Hardcode** these data () right in the form

Basically these constant options (values will never change) are in the Database and have their own tables to avoid data duplication and they also have ManyToMany relationships with posts.

But wouldn't be better to hardcode these options in the selectable fields rather than making bunch of **queries** to the database to get these options?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a single configuration table in database. Then you can emit a single query to read all values you require.

Read once from DB on start up and then cache/save in your application.

Comment: So I will have one table with all of the options for the form but when a user send the form, it will save the data to other tables? Do I understand it right?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd write a form generator that would, based on whatever's in the database, generate a form. If this form is generated very frequently and changes are very infrequent that's a candidate for *caching*.

Hard-coding is usually a bad idea for a multitude of reasons, but the biggest concern here is that your database and your form will differ in some subtle but important way. By having the form be generated by the database there's fewer chances of mistakes. You can also have the database be generated by the form (e.g. document store) but that's less common.